# Change (fade in/out) fixed background image when scrolling div into view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the fixed background image when scrolling each section (div) into view.

The background image should fade out as the user scrolls down and vice-versa. The images are laying on top of another via z-index, so I just need the overlying image to fade out when the section is reached.

I currently have this working for the first image only but do not know how to trigger the rest.

I am happy with using javascript.
Here is what I have so far - and it works great - nice and fluid.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#bg").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / $("#bg").height());
});
```

```css
.divOne {
  height: 2000px;
}

.divTwo {
  height: 2000px;
}

.divThree {
  height: 2000px;
}

.divFour {
  height: 2000px;
}

.backgrounds {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bg1 {
  background-image: url("http://techespresso.ca/assets/images/bg/whiteHouseStreet.gif");
  z-index: 4;
}

.bg2 {
  background-image: url("http://techespresso.ca/assets/images/bg/techespresso.jpg");
  z-index: 3;
}

.bg3 {
  background-image: url("http://techespresso.ca/assets/images/bg/techespresso_1.jpg");
  z-index: 2;
}

.bg4 {
  background-image: url("http://techespresso.ca/assets/images/bg/techespresso_2.jpg");
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<HTML>

<head>
  <title>Fade Fixed Images</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="divOne">Div-One</div>
  <div class="divTwo">Div-Two</div>
  <div class="divThree">Div-Three</div>
  <div class="divFour">Div-Four</div>

  <div class="backgrounds bg" id="bg"></div>
  <div class="backgrounds bg2" id="bg2"></div>
  <div class="backgrounds bg3" id="bg3"></div>
  <div class="backgrounds bg4" id="bg4"></div>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Can you post the full code.

Comment: I added the code for better orientation

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Scroll event to trigger the fade-in or fade-out, then you will have to add an event listener for the "mousewheel" event (for chrome) and "DOMMouseScroll" for firefox. then get the wheel direction from the e.wheelDelta, something like this:

```
var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail  : evt.wheelDelta;
```

create a variable say, i, then increase or decrease the value of 'i' with delta value , and use the 'i' value to change the opacity of the divs, for eg:

```
  if (i >= 0 && i<= 3) {
    document.querySelector('.bg1').style.opacity = 1;
    document.querySelector('.bg2').style.opacity = 0;
    document.querySelector('.bg3').style.opacity = 0;
   }
```

if you want the opacity to change gradually, then do something like:

```
    document.querySelector('.bg1').style.opacity = (0.3-(0.1*i))*
    (1/(0.1*3));
    document.querySelector('.bg2').style.opacity = (0.1*i)*(1/(0.1*3));;
    document.querySelector('.bg3').style.opacity = 0;
```

Hope you get the idea.

Edit 1: I haven't tested if this is working perfectly based on your requirements. put the below code in the script tag at the bottom of the html page, just above closing body tag.

```
var i=0;

var myFunc = function(e){
var evt = window.event || e ;
var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail * (-1) : evt.wheelDelta;

if (delta < 0)
        i=i+(0.2); //apply your own increment value based on i
      if ((delta > 0 && i > 0)
        i=i-(0.2); //apply your own decrement value based on i

document.querySelector('.bg1').style.opacity = i;

document.querySelector('.bg2').style.opacity = 1-i;//apply your own formula 
document.querySelector('.bg3').style.opacity = 0;
}

document.addEventListener("mousewheel",myFunc,false);
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example as per my code above?

Comment: i have edited the answer , see if this helps, this is based on pure javascript, not jquery

Comment: also in your original question, the script is outside the body tag, i think the script has to be inside the body, at the bottom, just check it once